# Set selected value dynamically using ternary operator in option tag

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an update form for a automobile database in PHP.

I get the "mid" of the current value of the car model like this:

```
$current_mid= $row['mid'];
```

Then I display it in a drop down box populated with all the models and set the "selected" value based on what the current model is:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($carResult))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$row['mid'].'"'.(($row['mid'] == $current_mid )? 'selected="selected"' : '').'>' .$row['modelName'].'</option>';
}
```

When I run this, I do see all the models, but the 'selected' value is never set.

Also, when I examine the html code in the browser, I see errors like this between each value:

> ```
> Notice:  Undefined index: mid in C:\xampp\htdocs\CarMakes\updateCar.php on line 90
> ```

line 90 is the echo line above.

I'm not sure why it's not working and why the browser is getting those errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please add the sql request ?

Comment: the `$row['modelName']` is working ? Because when I execute your php code ( I replace the values ), it's working

Comment: @Fizik26 Yes, one of the options looks like this: <option value="">Ford</option>